# Points on which function is invertible?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

$f: \mathbb R ^{2}\mapsto \mathbb R ^{2}$

$f(x,y)\mapsto((x-y)^{2}+1,  x-y^{3}-2)$

For which points is this function invertible?

I calculated the Jacobian matrix, but what should I do next to get specific points?

$J=\begin{pmatrix} 2x-2y & -2x+2y\\ 1 & -3y^{2}   \end{pmatrix}  $

Comment: The last entry in $J$ should be $-3y^2$

Comment: By invertible I assume you mean locally invertible?

Comment: @zhw yes i mean that

Answer (score 1):

The function will be invertible as long as the determinant of its Jacobian is not 0.  Wasn't that the reason you found the Jacobian in the first place?

Comment: Yes. But with two unknowns, I cant solve equation.

Comment: With two unknowns, the equation gives a _relation_ between the coordinates of the points:  there is an infinite number of such points.

Answer (score 1):

$\det(J) = (2x-2y)(-3y^2) + (2x -2y) = (2x-2y)(-3y^2+1) = 0$

The function is not invertable when $x= y$ or when $y = +-1/√3$

Of course, this is accepting that $J$ is correct.

Comment: In general, not quite true; think about $f(x,y) = (x^3, y)$.